# object equals(object) method working nature

Tags: java, arrays, string, oop, object

While I am going through a question in hackerrank. I wrote imperfect code and I got the wrong answer for it but I wonder how I got that
Note: I know that by changing the return statement as `return java.util.Arrays.equals(aa,bb);` . I get the correct answer

```
static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    a=a.toLowerCase();
    b=b.toLowerCase();
    char aa[]=a.toCharArray();
    char bb[]=b.toCharArray();
    
    if(a.length()!=b.length())
    return false;
    else
    {
        java.util.Arrays.sort(aa);
        java.util.Arrays.sort(bb);
        System.out.println(aa.equals(bb));
    
        return aa.equals(bb);
    }
```

Code: to determine whether both the string contains the same frequency of characters and return true for same and false for the opposite respectively. The above code always returning false
It thought as aa is not an instance of String. I came to this phenomenon of seeing the below internal code of  String_object.equals(String_object) method.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {  
  if (this == anObject) {  
      return true;  
  }  
  if (anObject instanceof String) {  
      String anotherString = (String) anObject;  
      int n = value.length;  
      if (n == anotherString.value.length) {  
          char v1[] = value;  
          char v2[] = anotherString.value;  
          int i = 0;  
          while (n-- != 0) {  
              if (v1[i] != v2[i])  
                      return false;  
              i++;  
          }  
          return true;  
      }  
  }  
  return false;
```

}

So, I tried the code snippet of my original code with Character class and char array
It is working fine for the Character class but not for the char array.

```
Character a='a';
Character b='a';
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); //return true
```

but if we make try with Char array. It returns wrong.

```
char [] a={'a'};
char [] b={'b'};
System.out.println(a.equals(b));//return false always ( I thought it was because as a is not object of type String.
```

My doubt: Why it works with the Character class but not for the char array? As per the .equals() method code, it should pass false for Character class too but it is not why?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a.equals(b) is the same as a == b, i.e. is it the same array.
> Arrays.equals(aa, bb) compares the contents of the arrays.

From Java doc;

> The Character class wraps a value of the primitive type char in an
> object.An object of type Character contains a single field whose type
> is char. Object type uses equals method for equals comparasion
> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/character-equals-method-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: a==b and a.equals(b) are not same sir. a==b checks for reference of both are equals or not where as .equals method checks for contents in a and b. I appreciate your efforts, sir.

Comment: As I mention, this is the case for arrays, which is to only compare the references. it was designed this way for all mutable data types and only compared contents for immutable types eg String vs StringBuilder.

Comment: So, sir, I have a question that does there is an override method for the Character class in the equals method but not for the array? may I correct the answer?
From your answer, I came to knowledge that
1. for arrays .equals() method and a==b works same.
2.The code I placed for the internal working of equals method wrong?
if so can you please provide a link for the correct equals method sir?
Thank you.